# Request on url having mandarin character

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, internationalization

Trying to fetch content on below url but not working with requests module. although link opens up on browser. How to Get link using requests library

```
In [2]: requests.get('http://www.dwconstir.com/inc/download.asp?FileName=3Q17%20%uC2E4%uC801PT_ENG.pdf')
Out[2]: <Response [400]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to download a PDF. You can do that using **[urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)**

**Sample**

```
import urllib2

src_url = "http://www.dwconstir.com/inc/download.asp?FileName=3Q17%20%uC2E4%uC801PT_ENG.pdf"
path = "DEST_PATH"  #Folder location where you want to download the file.
response = urllib2.urlopen(src_url)
file = open(path + "document.pdf", 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
```

**Using requests**

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.dwconstir.com/inc/download.asp?FileName=3Q17%20%uC2E4%uC801PT_ENG.pdf'
path = "DEST_PATH"  #Folder location where you want to download the file.
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open(path + "document.pdf", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```